# UIAutomation UIButton onClick event

Tags: iphone, uibutton, ios-ui-automation

How to get the onlick event for a UIButton in UIAutomation script in iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

For the first button in your main window:

```
 UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[0].tap();
```

Also have a look at [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Built-InInstruments/Built-InInstruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH6-SW75) by Apple for all the steps to your test script running.